# Memory Optimization of Java Collectors.toMap

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a function that converts a list to a map.  The map's size won't change after this function is called.  I'm trying to decide between the following two implementations:

```
Map<Long, Object> listToMap(List<Object> objs) {
        /* Implementation One: */

        Map<Long, Object> map = new HashMap<>(objs.size(), 1);
        for (Object obj : objs) {
            map.put(obj.getKey(), obj);
        }
        return map;

        /* Implementation Two: */

        return objs.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Object::getKey, obj -> obj));

    }
```

In the first implementation, I've allocated just enough memory for all the elements by using a load factor of 1 and the list's size.  This ensures that a resize operation won't be performed.  Then, I iterate through the list and add elements one-by-one.

In the second implementation, I use Java 8 streams for better readability.

My question is: will the second implementation involve multiple resizes of the HashMap or has it been optimized to allocate just enough memory?

Comment: You can have the best of both worlds using the [`toMap()` overload](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-) that accepts a map supplier. But I don't see why you're convinced a load factor of 1 is ideal. It'll make lookups less efficient.

Comment: Why does a load factor affect lookups?

Comment: Try it and see?

Comment: It means it'll have only as many buckets as there are entries, which increases the likelihood of collisions. See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) for more detail.

Comment: @shmosel Makes sense, thanks

Comment: To answer your question, the standard implementation simply uses `HashMap::new`, so there's no optimization for sized streams. It probably wouldn't be a good idea either, since it would over-allocate when executing in parallel.

Comment: Load factor will in-and-of-itself not affect performance, the number of buckets in the internal hash table will. Normally, load factor is used to tell the HashMap when to re-size the hash table. Default load factor of 75% has been found to be a good compromise of size vs performance, so unless you know better, stick with that, which means you need to create the HashMap with a size of `objs.size() / 75%` aka `objs.size() / (3/4)` aka `objs.size() * 4 / 3 + 1` (+1 to force rounding up). If you do that, any load factor of 75% or more will not resize the hash table (if map.size() <= objs.size()).

Comment: A load factor of `1` would be appropriate only if you had a [perfect hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function) and ensured that the `HashMap` code used the hash unmodified.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The second implementation will involve multiple resizes of the HashMap.

I determined this by simply running it in a debugger and breaking every time the hash map gets resized. First I tweaked the code you posted to make it compile on my system:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
    for(int i=0; i<100000; i++) {
      list.add(new Integer(i));
    }
    new Test().listToMap(list);
  }

    Map<Integer, Object> listToMap(List<Object> objs) {
        return objs.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Object::hashCode, obj -> obj));
    }
}
```

Then I compiled it and ran it in the debugger until it hit `listToMap`:

```
$ javac Test.java && jdb Test
Initializing jdb ...
> stop in Test.listToMap
Deferring breakpoint Test.listToMap.
It will be set after the class is loaded.
> run
run Test
Set uncaught java.lang.Throwable
Set deferred uncaught java.lang.Throwable
>
VM Started: Set deferred breakpoint Test.listToMap

Breakpoint hit: "thread=main", Test.listToMap(), line=14 bci=0
14            return objs.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Object::hashCode, obj -> obj));

main[1]
```

Then I set a breakpoint in `java.util.HashMap.resize` and continued:

```
main[1] stop in java.util.HashMap.resize
Set breakpoint java.util.HashMap.resize
main[1] cont
>
Breakpoint hit: "thread=main", java.util.HashMap.resize(), line=678 bci=0

main[1]
```

and `cont`inued some more until I got bored:

```
main[1] cont
>
Breakpoint hit: "thread=main", java.util.HashMap.resize(), line=678 bci=0

main[1] cont
>
Breakpoint hit: "thread=main", java.util.HashMap.resize(), line=678 bci=0

main[1] cont
>
Breakpoint hit: "thread=main", java.util.HashMap.resize(), line=678 bci=0

main[1] cont
>
Breakpoint hit: "thread=main", java.util.HashMap.resize(), line=678 bci=0

main[1] cont
>
Breakpoint hit: "thread=main", java.util.HashMap.resize(), 
line=678 bci=0

main[1] print size
 size = 3073
main[1] cont
>
Breakpoint hit: "thread=main", java.util.HashMap.resize(), line=678 bci=0

main[1] print size
 size = 6145
main[1] cont
>
Breakpoint hit: "thread=main", java.util.HashMap.resize(), line=678 bci=0

main[1] print size
 size = 12289
```

So yes: it most definitely keeps resizing over and over.

Answer (score 7):

> Will the second implementation involve multiple resizes of the HashMap or has it been optimized to allocate just enough memory?

In your code, the former.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51333961/139985

It is worth noting that for your current implementation:

1. Much of the extra memory consumed by resizing will be reclaimed on the next GC run.
2. After the `collect` finishes, you could still end up with a main hash array that is up to 2 times too big.  The memory "wasted" could be up to 8 bytes per entry in the table, but on average it will be 4 bytes per entry.
3. Even so, the hash entry nodes will be the largest consumer of memory in a `HashMap`.  Each entry consumes roughly 32 bytes ... in addition to the space used to represent the key and value.

<sup>(The above numbers assume 64 bit references.)</sup>

---

As an alternative, if you use the [4 argument overload](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-) of `toMap()` you can provide a `Supplier` to create the `Map` to be populated.  That allows you to do the following:

- Allocate a `HashMap` with an initial capacity large enough to avoid resizing, but not too large.
- Use a (hypothetical) alternative implementation of `Map` which uses less memory per entry than `HashMap`.
- Create a wrapper to populate a map-like object that doesn't implement `Map<K,V>` ... for your `K` and `V` types.  (For example, you could potentially use `TLongObjectHashMap` from the GNU Trove library.)

(In the latter two cases, the goal is to find a `Map` or "map-like" class that uses less memory (for your `K` and `V` types) but still has appropriate performance for lookups.)

Answer (score 2):

Summing up what everyone else said and adding a little, here's a way to do it using a custom `Collector`. However, you should keep in mind two things:

1. Continuing the thought of [Stephen C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/139985/stephen-c) from [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51333730/memory-optimization-of-java-collectors-tomap/51334160#51334160), you should't really be worried about optimizing such cases until you found out it really is a performance bottleneck in your application. As [Donald Knuth](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth) said, "premature optimization is the root of all evil".
2. As [shmosel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1553851/shmosel) pointed out in a comment, a `Collector` that allocates a `HashMap` with a predefined size will over-allocate if said `Collector` is used in a parallel mode. Therefore, the `Collector` I propose doesn't support parallel collection.

Having said that, you can write the following generic `Collector`s:

```
public class ExtraCollectors {

    public static <T, K, V> Collector<T, ?, HashMap<K, V>> toSizedMap(
            Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper, Function<? super T, ? extends V> valueMapper, int size) {
        return toSequentialMap(
                () -> com.google.common.collect.Maps.newHashMapWithExpectedSize(size),
                keyMapper, valueMapper, Collector.Characteristics.UNORDERED
        );
    }

    public static <T, K, V, M extends Map<K, V>> Collector<T, ?, M> toSequentialMap(
            Supplier<M> mapSupplier, Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper,
            Function<? super T, ? extends V> valueMapper, Collector.Characteristics... characteristics) {
        return Collector.of(
                mapSupplier,
                (map, element) -> map.merge(
                        keyMapper.apply(element), valueMapper.apply(element), ExtraCollectors::mergeUnsupported
                ),
                ExtraCollectors::combineUnsupported,
                characteristics
        );
    }

    private static <T> T mergeUnsupported(T valueA, T valueB) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("This Collector does not support merging.");
    }

    private static <A> A combineUnsupported(A accumulatorA, A accumulatorB) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("This Collector does not support parallel streams.");
    }
}
```

Note that I used Guava's [Maps.newHashMapWithExpectedSize](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/25.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#newHashMapWithExpectedSize-int-) so that you get a `HashMap` with exactly the size you need (it does roughly what [Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5221149/andreas) explained in his comment to your question). If you don't have a dependency on [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) (and don't want to have), you can just copy the [Maps.capacity](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Maps.java) method to your codebase.

Using the `ExtraCollectors.toSizedMap()` method defined above, your conversion method would look as follows:

```
Map<Long, KeyedObject> listToMap(List<? extends KeyedObject> objs) {
    return objs.stream().collect(ExtraCollectors.toSizedMap(KeyedObject::getKey, obj -> obj, objs.size()));

}
```

Still, if you really want maximum performance (at the price of reusability), you might skip the `Stream` API altogether, and apply your solution 1 but with `Maps.newHashMapWithExpectedSize` to get the `HashMap`'s size right.